# Why I got django OperationalError: no such table: live_person while I had this table inside my models file?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

I couldn't understand the reason of this error message: OperationalError: no such table
[while in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgiiA.png)

the model file have this table

Comment: It seems that you forgot to actually create the tables in the database. They don't appear there automatically. Run `python manage.py migrate` to do so.

Comment: welcome to SO: what have you done regarding migration? which django version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

run these :

to make your migration :

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then to apply it on database :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I did it but nothing

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by creating a table with SQLite command:
    python manage.py dbshell
    CREATE TABLE database_name.table_name(
    column1 datatype  PRIMARY KEY(one or more columns),
    column2 datatype,
    column3 datatype,
    .....
    columnN datatype,
    );
   exit
now run makemigrations command followed by migrate